# Multiple controllers in a closure angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created 2 controllers inside a closure:

```
_closure = (function(){

var _One; 
var _Two;


//register module- left out for brevity

function ctrlOne($scope){

this.model = {
a : 'a'
b:'b'
}

_One = $scope;

}

function ctrlTwo($scope){

this.model = {
c : 'c'
d:'d'
}

_Two = $scope;

}

//assign controllers to module- left out for brevity


var publicMethods = {

saveAll: function(){

// access both the models in this function. 

}


}


})()
```

I want to access the models in my public function (as I am currently retrofitting angular in my existing framework). I wonder if assigning references to the scope of both the controllers is the right thing to do? Here I have just kept a pointer to both $scope (in _One and _Two) and then would try to access their respective models in the SaveAll public method. Is this the right way to go about it?

Comment: Typically, the controller is the one initiating a call to save, not the other way around. It's difficult to know exactly what you are trying to accomplish by "retrofitting angular", but I feel that you are about to venture into a "bad place". So, to put it bluntly, the right way to go about it is to abandon this idea as early as possible, while you have your sanity intact. :)

Comment: I have that funny feeling as well :) But the size of the application that is already there and the existing javascript framework would require a lot of work to change. What I was hoping was to implement something in angular and get other developers' buy-in before replacing the underlying one with angular. So its either give it up for good, or die trying ;) But yes your comment makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

There's several things wrong with this, and I agree with New Dev that you should 'abandon this idea as early as possible'

1) You aren't returning anything in this IIFE, so the `_closure` variable will become `undefined`

2) In Angular, the `$scope` object *is the model*, and a new `$scope` gets passed into each controller function. So you could have things like:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('ctrlOne', function($scope){
  $scope.a = 'a';
  $scope.b = 'b';
})
.controller('ctrlTwo', function($scope){
  $scope.c = 'c';
  $scope.d = 'd';
});
```

3) I'm not sure how you're currently hooking up the controllers to the app, so maybe the `this.model` convention works, but you generally don't use the keyword `this` inside controllers.

4) Keeping a pointer to both $scopes in `_One` and `_Two` is not the right way to go about this. Rather than finding a way to maintain access to a particular controller's scope outside of that controller function, you would use a [provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) (either a service or factory) in place of your public methods. Providers hold all business logic for an app, and sounds like that's what your public functions are doing (i.e. `saveAll`).

Retrofitting something with angular can be pretty quick - but only if you know what you're doing. Angular is really confusing and hard to pick up, and unless you know your tools well you're going to be pretty clunky with them. I suggest starting with [ng-newsletter's fantastic beginner tutorial](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/beginner2expert-how_to_start.html)